# Return powershell object variable in table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In Powershell you can use the Get-ADUser commandlet to get all users in Active Directory.  You can then pipe this to Format-Table to list some of the values in a table.

However, some of the values returned are also objects, for example the users manager.

How do I display a property of this child-object alongside properties of the parent - e.g. manager's name or email address?

I tried the following, but no joy:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties name, mail, manager | Format-table name, mail manager.name
```

Is there are simple way to do this?

Comment: What i Have done with this is a separate lookup with $_.Manager, and then a custom table. A little more code, and its really meant for exported data...

Comment: any further hints on how to do this? Or even links to something that talks you through this - so far I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manager property is just a string (not an object with sub-properties). Two options:

1) Extract the name from the manager's DN (faster):

```
... | select Name,mail,@{n='manager';e={$_.manager -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'}}
```

2) Get the name with an additional Get-ADUser call (slower):

```
... | select Name,mail,@{n='manager';e={(Get-ADUser $_.manager).Name}}
```

And you can always pipe to Foreach-Object and create a custom object for each user.

Comment: Thanks so much - first option does just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with calculated properties? Try something like that:

```
 Get-ADUser -Properties name,mail,manager | Format-Table @{n="Manager Name";e={(Get-Aduser -Filter { DistinguishedName -eq $_.manager }).Name}}
```